# Converse of Impagliazzo, Kabanets, Wigderson

Tags: complexity-theory, circuits

I am trying to prove that $\text{NEXP} = \text{MA} \Rightarrow \text{NEXP} \subseteq P/\text{Poly}$. I tried to approach the result via trying out the contrapositive, that $\text{NEXP} \nsubseteq P/\text{Poly} \Rightarrow \text{NEXP} \ne \text{MA}$ but I couldn't get anywhere. Can anyone give me a hint to proceed?

Comment: It seems easier to prove it directly rather than via the contrapositive.

Comment: Can you give a hint as how to proceed in that direction? From NEXP=MA we get NEXP=EXP, what all complexity results can I get from this?

Comment: See Theorem 27 in [IKW](https://www.math.ias.edu/~avi/PUBLICATIONS/MYPAPERS/IKW02/IKW02.pdf).

Comment: Thanks @YuvalFilmus